# How to build salesforce report on a parent object having childs through Master detail and lookup relationships

Tags: custom-reports

Object A has M-D Relationship with Object B (A-Master, B-Child)

Object A has Lookup Relationship from Object C (A-Parent, C-Child)

Object A has Lookup Relationship from Object D (A-Parent, D-Child)

Object D has Lookup Relationship from Object C (D-Parent, C-Child)

We need all the records of A and related B Records. In addition, 
We need the related C records, if not just a hyphen and 
We need the related D records, if not just a hyphen

In brief, Object A is the Parent for the objects which are related through Master Detail and Lookup relationships. How to create a report to include all the objects? (All the records of object A are mandatory).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

You can't, without using a Joined Report.

If you envision the Salesforce object model as a tree, with Object A at the top:

```
                   A
                 / |  \
                /  |   \
               B   D    \
                    \--- C
```

Salesforce reporting only permits you to descend only one branch of the tree at each level. So you could construct a report of A and B, a report of A and D, a report of A and C, a report of D and C, or a report of A and D and C.

What you can't do is descend two branches of the tree on the same level. So you cannot, for example, construct a report on A with B and D.

You can also construct your report from the bottom up by traversing lookups from the child to the parent. So, for example, you could go from C to D to A. You would not be able to then descend the hierarchy from A, however.

Alternatives include:

- Building multiple reports starting from A and uniting them in a Joined Report, grouped across report blocks by some value on A.
- Using roll-up summaries to roll up key data points from, for example, B to A, so they can be reported on in an A and C report.
- Using a third-party reporting or business analytics application.